# htaccess rewrite from url query

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need some help trying to redirect a query to a url.

www.example.com/?categoryID=79
needs to redirect to
www.example.com/catname

where catname is just a string, it has no variables.

Here's what I tried so far:
I began with a humble approach that failed horribly:

```
redirect 301 /?CategoryID=79 http://www.example.com/catname/   

then i moved on to mod_rewrite :  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} CategoryID=79$ 
RewriteRule (.*) /catname/? [R=301,L]
```

Both did not work and I'm actually stomped.
any help would be appreciated.

Just to be clear, In the end i'll have many of these rules redirecting to various category names.

*important* - it's not enough for `/catname` to display the proper page, the request with the query parameter **must** redirect to the new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule should work for you **as first rule in your .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?CategoryID=79[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /catname/? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: That's amazing :)

Any chance you can explain what's going on in those two lines of code? Or if you can refer me to any resources on the matter? Most resources are found I honestly could not follow.

Comment: Good resource is http://askapache.com and about this rule I am using `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable here. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and **it doesn't get overwritten after execution of other rewrite rules**. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Thanks for that answer, Could you please specify a `RewriteCond` for a URL that looks `www.example.com/?categoryID=79?OK=100` - I tried expanding from your example but that did not work too well :)

Comment: You cannot match URL and host name both in same `RewriteCond` For matching host name you need to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$` and another `RewriteCond` For matching URI.

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear, the domain name is purely an example, it can be any domain, I'm specifically interested in catching the two GET parameters, `categoryID` and `OK` Your code works perfectl with one but where would i insert the other? :)

Comment: For capturing 2 query parameters use: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?CategoryID=79&OK=([^&]+)[&\s]`, then use `%1` and `%2` in the target URI.